# Lorentz symmetry and Noether's theorem

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, noethers-theorem, lorentz-symmetry

I'm trying to overcome some misunderstanding that I have in Noether's theorem.

There is formula in David Gross's Lectures on QFT for Noether's theorem:

$$J^\mu_\alpha=\mathcal{L}X^\mu_\alpha+\Pi^\mu_i\left[\Psi_{i\alpha}-\partial_\nu\phi_i X^i_\alpha\right]$$
$J^\mu_\alpha$ - conserved vector current, $\Pi^\mu_i$-canonical momentum, $X^\mu_\alpha$ and $\Psi_{i\alpha}$ are generators of symmetry which are defined by $$x'^\mu=x^\mu+X^\mu_\alpha \omega^\alpha,$$
$$\phi'(x'^\mu)=\phi(x^\mu)+\Psi_{i\alpha} \omega^\alpha,$$

Particularly I'm working out Lorentz symmetry:

$$x'^\mu=\Lambda^\mu_\nu x^\nu$$

Infinitesimal version of this transformation is: $\Lambda^\mu_\nu=\delta^\mu_\nu+\omega^\mu_\nu$, where $\omega^\mu_\nu=-\omega^\nu_\mu$ is antisymmetric.

**So, my problem that I dont understand why** (they write this expression in many sources, not only in Gross)
$$X^{\mu,\alpha}_\beta=\delta^\mu_\alpha x^\beta-\delta^\mu_\beta x^\alpha$$.

If I'm calculating $X^{\mu,\alpha}_\beta\omega^\beta_\alpha$, I get $2\omega^\mu_\nu x^\nu$, not the $\omega^\mu_\nu x^\nu$. Also I've done this calculation:
$$f(x'^\mu)=f(x^\mu+\omega^\mu_\alpha x^\alpha)\approx f(x^\mu)+\omega_{\alpha \mu}x^\alpha \partial^\mu f = f(x^\mu) + \frac 1 2 \omega_{\alpha \mu} \left(x^\mu \partial^\alpha-x^\alpha \partial^\mu \right)f $$

If $f=x^\mu$ (coordinate function), then $$X^{\mu,\alpha}_\beta=\frac 12\left(\delta^\mu_\alpha x^\beta-\delta^\mu_\beta x^\alpha\right).$$

*What exactly am I doing wrong?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this calculation is the answer for your question:

$$\sum_{\alpha,\mu}\frac 1 2 \omega_{\alpha \mu} \left(x^\mu \partial^\alpha-x^\alpha \partial^\mu \right)=\frac 1 2 \sum_{\alpha<\mu}\omega_{\alpha \mu} \left(x^\mu \partial^\alpha-x^\alpha \partial^\mu \right)+\frac 1 2 \sum_{\mu<\alpha}\omega_{\alpha \mu} \left(x^\mu \partial^\alpha-x^\alpha \partial^\mu \right)=\frac 1 2 \sum_{\alpha<\mu}\omega_{\alpha \mu} \left(x^\mu \partial^\alpha-x^\alpha \partial^\mu \right)+\frac 1 2 \sum_{\alpha<\mu}\omega_{\mu\alpha } \left(x^\alpha  \partial^\mu-x^\mu \partial^\alpha  \right)=\frac 1 2 \sum_{\alpha<\mu}\omega_{\alpha \mu} \left(x^\mu \partial^\alpha-x^\alpha \partial^\mu \right)+\frac 1 2 \sum_{\alpha<\mu}\omega_{\alpha \mu} \left(x^\mu \partial^\alpha-x^\alpha \partial^\mu \right)=\sum_{\alpha<\mu}\omega_{\alpha \mu} \left(x^\mu \partial^\alpha-x^\alpha \partial^\mu \right)$$

Where I

1. Splited sum in "$\alpha<\mu$" and "$\mu<\alpha$" parts.
2. Changed $\alpha \leftrightarrow \mu$
3. Used antisymmetric property of $\omega_{\alpha \mu}$ and $\left(x^\mu \partial^\alpha-x^\alpha \partial^\mu \right)$

Answer (score 2):

Your expression is wrong and you got things mixed up somewhere. With the notation you used, it should be:
$$J^μ_α = \mathcal{L} X^μ_α + Π^{μi} \left[Ψ_{iα} - ∂_νφ_i X^ν_α\right],$$
where the respective infinitesimal transforms are:
$$Δφ_i = Ψ_{iα} ω^α,\quad Δx^μ = X^μ_α ω^α,$$
and $Π^{μi}$ is the Lagrangian derivative
$$Π^{μi} = \frac{∂\mathcal{L}}{∂\left({∂_μφ_i}\right)},$$
**not** the canonical stress tensor density. The canonical stress tensor density, in your notation, which I'll denote here by $Π^μ_ν$, is
$$Π^μ_ν = Π^{μi} ∂_νφ_i - δ^μ_ν \mathcal{L},$$
so that you could write $J^μ_α$, just as well, as:
$$J^μ_α = Π^{μi} Ψ_{iα} - Π^μ_ν X^ν_α;$$
i.e.
$$J^μ = J^μ_α ω^α = Π^{μi} Δφ_i - Π^μ_ν Δx^ν.$$
It's best to keep it as $J^μ$, without the decomposition.

For your application,
$$Δφ_i = 0, \quad Δx^ν = ω^ν_ρ x^ρ.$$
Then
$$J^μ = -Π^μ_ν Δx^ν = -Π^μ_ν ω^ν_ρ x^ρ.$$
The transform coefficients have the property:
$$ω^ν_ρ = g_{μρ} ω^{νμ}, \quad ω^{νμ} = -ω^{μν},$$
where $g_{μρ}$ are the coefficients of a non-degenerate metric. Equivalently,
$$g_{μρ} ω^ρ_ν + g_{νρ} ω^ρ_μ = 0,$$
or just
$$ω_{νμ} = -ω_{μν}, \quad ω_{μν} = g_{μρ} ω^ρ_ν,$$
if you use the metric to lower the indexes, instead. The transform is defined as one that preserves the metric.

Thus, upon substitution:
$$J^μ = -Π^μ_ν ω^ν_ρ x^ρ = -Π^μ_ν ω^{νσ} g_{ρσ} x^ρ.$$
Since $ω^{νσ} = -ω^{σν}$, then it can be anti-symmetrized:
$$J^μ = \frac12 ω^{νσ} x^ρ \left(Π^μ_σ g_{ρν} - Π^μ_ν g_{ρσ}\right).$$
If you lower the coordinates' indices, $x_σ = g_{ρσ}x^ρ$, then you can also write this as:
$$J^μ = \frac12 ω^{νσ} \left(x_ν Π^μ_σ - x_σ Π^μ_ν\right) = \frac12 ω^{νσ} J^μ_{νσ},\quad J^μ_{νσ} = x_ν Π^μ_σ - x_σ Π^μ_ν.$$

If, instead, you do it with the indices in the opposite positions, then it will be:
$$J^μ = \frac12 ω_{νσ} \left(x^ν Π^{μσ} - x^σ Π^{μν}\right) = \frac12 ω_{νσ} J^{μνσ},\quad J^{μνσ} = x^ν Π^{μσ} - x^σ Π^{μν},$$
where $Π^{μν} = Π^μ_ρ g^{ρν}$.

The same anti-symmetrization applies to the transform $Δx^μ$:
$$Δx^μ = ω^μ_ν x^ν = ω^{ρσ} δ^μ_ρ g_{σν} x^ν = \frac12 ω^{ρσ} \left(δ^μ_ρ g_{σν} - δ^μ_σ g_{ρν}\right) x^ν.$$
or:
$$Δx^μ = \frac12 ω^{αβ} X_{αβμ}^ν x^ν, \quad X_{αβμ}^ν = δ^μ_α g_{βν} - δ^μ_β g_{αν}.$$
If you swap the $β$ index, then you'll get:
$$Δx^μ = \frac12 ω^α_β X_{αμ}^{βν} x^ν, \quad X_{αμ}^{βν} = δ^μ_α δ^β_ν - g^{βμ} g_{αν},$$
where $g^{βν}$ are the coefficients of the inverse of the metric.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the few times when using the Einstein convention isn't helpful: recall that in Noether's theorem you need to sum over the *independent* parameters of your transformation, which is usually trivial but, for Lorentz transformations, you need to be careful because of the antisymmetry of $\omega_{\mu\nu}$, which implies that you have only 6 generators.

When you sum over $\alpha,\mu$ using the Einstein convention, you're summing twelve terms (and double counting the contribution of each generator). To have a sum that takes into account that you only have six, you need to sum using, say, $\alpha>\mu$, and that will imply not using the Einstein convention for a while. If you do that you don't get the factor if 1/2.