# Antisymmetry of Infinitesimal Lorentz Transformations and Noether Currents

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry, noethers-theorem, classical-field-theory

I am going through the derivation for the six Noether currents associated with Lorentz transformations; however, I do not understand the final step in the derivation. One ends up with the following expression for the Noether current

$$j^\mu = -\omega^\lambda{}_\mu T^\nu{}_\lambda x^\mu$$

where $\omega^\lambda{}_\mu$ is an infinitesimally small Lorentz transformation. This is antisymmetric, such that $\omega^\lambda{}_\mu=-\omega_\mu{}^\lambda$ To obtain

$$M^{\mu \nu \rho}=x^{\nu}T^{\mu \rho}-x^{\rho}T^{\mu \nu}$$

one utilizes this symmetry; however, I don't understand how this is so

Comment: Did you manage to solve this question? I don't understand it either

Comment: I meet this problem as well. And I found this https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/134581/lorentz-symmetry-and-noethers-theorem?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates transform as $δx^μ = ε^μ + ω^μ_ν x^ν$. The coordinate differentials transform by way of $δd(⋯) = dδ(⋯)$, so that
$$δ\left(dx^μ\right) = d\left(δx^μ\right) = d\left(ε^μ + ω^μ_ν x^ν\right) = ω^μ_ν dx^ν.$$
The transform on the metric components is determined by the requirement that $g_{μν} dx^μ dx^ν$ be invariant. Thus,
$$\begin{align}
0
&= δ\left(g_{μν} dx^μ dx^ν\right)\\
&= δ\left(g_{μν}\right) dx^μ dx^ν + g_{μν} δ\left(dx^μ\right) dx^ν + g_{μν} dx^μ δ\left(dx^ν\right)\\
&= δ\left(g_{μν}\right) dx^μ dx^ν + g_{μν} \left(ω^μ_ρ dx^ρ\right) dx^ν + g_{μν} dx^μ \left(ω^ν_ρ dx^ρ\right)\\
&= δ\left(g_{μν}\right) dx^μ dx^ν + g_{ρν} ω^ρ_μ dx^μ dx^ν + g_{μρ} ω^ρ_ν dx^μ dx^ν\\
&= \left(δ\left(g_{μν}\right) + g_{ρν} ω^ρ_μ + g_{μρ} ω^ρ_ν\right) dx^μ dx^ν.
\end{align}$$
Component-wise, this reduces to:
$$δ\left(g_{μν}\right) + g_{ρν} ω^ρ_μ + g_{μρ} ω^ρ_ν = 0.$$

If the metric components are constants, then $δg_{μν} = 0$ and, as a result,
$$g_{ρν} ω^ρ_μ + g_{μρ} ω^ρ_ν = 0.$$
That's anti-symmetry when you rewrite it as
$$ω_{νμ} + ω_{μν} = 0\quad\left(ω_{μν} = g_{μρ} ω^ρ_ν\right).$$
For Minkowski geometry, the components of the metric are constant. So, this applies to Minkowski geometry and - thus - to Lorentz transforms.

In terms of your notation
$${ω_μ}^λ = g^{λν} ω_{μν} = -g^{λν} ω_{νμ} = -g^{λν} g_{νρ} ω^ρ_μ = -ω^λ_μ = -{ω^λ}_μ,$$
since I'm using $ω^λ_μ$ synonymously with your ${ω^λ}_μ$.